# How to fix this error "NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::Main#new. undefined method `polymorphic?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-admin

`model.rb`

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :video_categories
  has_many :videos, :through => :video_categories

end

class VideoCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :category
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :video_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :video_categories
end
```

I have 3 model. Many to Many association.

`rails_admin.rb`

```
config.model Video do
  list do
    field :url
    field :title
    field :description
    field :category, :belongs_to_association
    field :views
    field :votes
  end
  edit do
    field :url do
      required true
    end
    field :title do
      required true
    end
    field :description do
      html_attributes do
        {:maxlength => 200,
         :cols => 50}
      end
    end
    field :category, :belongs_to_association
    field :thumbnail
  end
end
```

Here's the error in browser:

[image]

Comment: Above there is a photo. 
 Near with model.rb "enter image description here "

Comment: Since the error is raised in the view, very little can be determined unless you also post the relevant controller and view files

Comment: thank you for your answer. I fixed this problem)